# Term (or "pattern"?) for "Do something if it's not already done"

Tags: design-patterns, patterns-and-practices, anti-patterns

Sounds pretty basic, I know, but I recently had a colleague tell me that a method called `startHttpServer` is too complicated to understand because it only starts the server if it's not already running. I find I get into trouble when I respond with, "Seriously? I've been doing this for decades - it's a common pattern in programming." More often than I care to admit he comes back with some documented evidence that shows that the entire programming community is behind his point of view and I end up feeling sheepish.

**Question**: Is there a documented design pattern behind the concept of a method that is a no-op if the action required is already in effect? Or, if not a pattern, does it have a name either? And if not, is there any reason to think it's too complicated to consider writing a method in this manner?

Comment: sounds like [caching](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/275065/31260) - and it is often considered complicated indeed (see also [How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6630/31260))

Comment: Thanks @gnat. I was honestly worried that someone would think I'm just trying to find ammunition for my point of view. I had originally added a statement at the end indicating that I'm open to whatever the community has to say, but I took it out to keep people from going down this path. You picked up the possibility anyway.

Comment: Is it something people often encounter, yes, is it a named pattern, no.

Comment: You got 3 different answers, but the best answer would be, apply them all: rename the original function, split its code into two functions (where one of the two now gets the name `startHttpServer`), and yes, the term "idempotent" applies here well.

Comment: What sort of counter-evidence does your colleague provide?  Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: I'm curious to see from where your colleague sources his quotes. At least around Stack Overflow and Software Engineering, this function would be at most badly named but wouldn't have any unusual behavior. Keep in mind that isn't because someone somewhere put something on a blog that it represents the entire view of the programming community. Even big names like Martin Fowler say some very weird things from time to time. We're all just humans.

Comment: Too complicated to understand? No. Potentially confusing? Yes.

Comment: “Do something if it's not already done” Btw. this might be a hint for not enough strong contracts and should be reserved for the cases where one really cannot know that something is already done. Example: EnsureThatImportantValueIsNotZero, DoSomethingElse, EnsureThatImportantValueIsStillNotZero, ...

Comment: I think a better way to think about "Do something if it's not already done" would be "Put the system on this state". Of course, if the system already is on that state, the method would do nothing - which would be the expected behavior.

Comment: If you "get in trouble" for responses of "Seriously?" Does he "get in trouble" for being a passive aggressive know it all?  If he can't show an actual error, he should keep it to himself.

Comment: Maybe if you call startHttpServer twice the second one should return "Seriously?"

Answer (score 127):

As NickWilliams [has already said](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/356349/234437): the concept the OP describes is called **idempotent** (noun **Idempotency**). It is indeed common practice, especially in high-level APIs.

### BUT: Rename the function.

Instead of `startHttpServer` call it `makeSureHttpServerIsRunning` or `ensureHttpServerIsRunning`.

When a function is called `startHttpServer`, readers expect it to start a HTTP server; when called ten times in a row, I'll have ten servers running.
Your function doesn't do that most of the time. Additionally, the name with "start" suggests that if I want only one server running I'll have to keep track of whether the function has already been called or not.

When a function is called `makeSureHttpServerIsRunning`, I assume it will do the necessary things to make sure that a HTTP server is running, most likely by checking if it is already running, and starting it otherwise. I also assume that the function makes sure the server is actually running (starting a server might involve some time where it is not quite running yet).

Comment: This. Personally I use "Ensure" instead. The point is that this should become a naming scheme that is understood in your team.

Comment: or have start throw an exception if its already started. like sqlconnection.open

Comment: I always use the "ensure" naming for "do if not already" function.

Comment: Another name I often see is getOrCreateSomething, which only create on first call and then just return something

Comment: "Readers expect it to start an http server; when called ten times in a row, I'll have ten servers running." - I tend to disagree, _especially_ if it's not taking a port number as a parameter.  And even if it is, I'd only expect to get 10 server instances if I pass 10 different port numbers.  Otherwise I'd expect it to start an http server on the standard/default/configured port if it can, and to fail otherwise (for instance with an 'address already in use' error when attempting to bind the socket).  Which is, essentially, idempotent behavior.

Comment: @aroth Are you sure you wouldn't expect it to attempt to find any available port and return it? Or just be badly written? ;)

Comment: That would give me Java fingers.  Please don't do this.

Comment: @jcast Better Java fingers than Objective-C fingers.

Comment: @jpmc26  I'd expect some convention like "a negative port means find any available port" and a positive port to mean what aroth suggests.

Comment: @aroth: In some cases, a useful behavior for calling "start" multiple times is to have each invocation ask the previous one to die off before starting itself.  That can be useful for services that do things like load configuration on startup or cache certain types of information that might become invalid in certain circumstances.

Comment: Everyone: Yes, "ensure" is better. @aroth: We expect different things from a function named startHttpServer. And that is exactly the problem with the function name. And supercat has another, reasonable but totally different expectation :-(

Comment: While I appreciate the method names you suggest, I'd not call this the typical meaning of "idempotence".

Comment: "When called ten times in a row, I'll have ten servers running." I don't think that as reader, you'd really assume that in practice, assuming that such code have ever been written in first place... In the case it's really meant to start 10 different servers, the functions would have different arguments visually indicating that... Fundamentally, there shouldn't be problem by intending to start something that have been started already, AKA "1*1=1". At high level, in user context, I'd care more about how long/natural/memorable the function's name is. In this regard, `startHttpServer` is better.

Comment: If you need to know how works the function in detail, learn it from source or documentation like for any other function. You learn it once, but you have to call it so much more often...

Comment: So now I am wondering what that *Ensure* nutrition drink does? What if I drink 2 in a row?

Answer (score 33):

Rename it to `EnsureServerRunning`.

Completely unambiguous and is clear that it makes sure it is running (if it isn't) without implying a restart if it is.

(Alternative: `StartServerIfNotRunning`?)

Comment: Most callers just care that the server is running after the call. How that is achieved, they don't care.

Answer (score 29):

Not really a design pattern but I would call your method **idempotent**. There term is usually used to refer to remote calls but the description seems the match what you are doing.

> Idempotent Methods. Methods can also have the property of
>   "idempotence" in that (aside from error or expiration issues) the
>   side-effects of N > 0 identical requests is the same as for a single
>   request. ([From W3.org](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html))

The server side effect here being that the http server is started once the method is called. I see nothing wrong with a method doing this.

If you need a design pattern I guess you could expose your httpServer as a singleton which is started when initialized.

Comment: The function is **not** *idempotent* if calling it once starts the http server, and calling it a second time doesn't. Thats literally the opposite of idempotence. It would be idempotent if *every* call started a new http server.

Comment: @Polygnome [Wikipedia defines idempotence as f(f(x)) = f(x)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) which generally matches Nick's description. Here the function input and output would be the implicit server state, so the “server is running” state would be a fixed point for this function. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the Wikipedia article here, could you link to other references?

Comment: @Polygnome: this answer is correct, idempotency refers to functions for which it does not matter if they are called once or more than once, the result keeps always the same. Here, the result is one running http service, independently from the number of times the function is called.

Comment: The confusion comes from the fact that idempotence at its core is a mathematical concept applied to functions. The definition is nice and simple for those and also works well for pure functional languages. As soon as you introduce side effects it gets complicated - you have to consider the environment you execute the function in as an (implicit) argument and output of the function. If that state is not modified by further calls to the function it is idempotent, otherwise it isn't. In this case the relevant state is "is http server running" - so the function is idempotent.

Comment: @Polygnome Sorry, you are wrong. Idempotent means that the request has the same effect whether it is executed once, or more than once.  Starting N http servers if N duplicates of the request are received is definitely not idempotent.

Comment: @Voo Idempotence in this context isn't the mathematical concept; it's just the same word being used in a different context. Mathematical functions don't require this software engineering version of idempotence because they **do not have side effects**.  Idempotence in software is a sometimes useful property of a **procedure** which mutates state: executing it two or more times has the same net effect on the state. Or at least the same effect as far as some particular point of view is concerned (which cares about some effects but possibly not some others).

Comment: In other words, mathematics functions and operators are all idempotent in the software engineering sense. Those which are computable can have counterparts in a functional programming language. Those computational counterparts will be effect free; effect free implies idempotent (in the software sense) because if something has no effect, evaluating it two or more times still has that same null effect.

Comment: @Kaz I just explained the origin of the term and how you have to adapt the definition to make it work for a non-functional programming language with side effects. And no the function absolutely is idempotent. There is  one relevant metastate in the environment: `httpServerIsRunning`. Evaluating the given function the first time will set this variable to true, evaluating it again won't change the state again. But I think we're in agreement on this, you just didn't read the question carefully enough: The whole thing is about *not* starting a second server if the function is called a second time.

Comment: side-note: A simple example of an idempotent function is `memcpy(dst, src, len)` with non-overlapping memory ranges.  A `memcpy` implementation can copy 8 (or 16 or 32) bytes at a time, and instead of copying the last up to 7 bytes one at a time, can do a possibly-overlapping copy of the last 8 bytes (if `len >= 8`).  If re-copying overlapping bytes wasn't idempotent, you couldn't do this optimization.  (Real implementations often use the same code as for `memmove`, so they check for overlap and copy up / down as required.)

Comment: @PeterCordes A non-overlapping `memcpy` is just a form of assignment with distracting details. Assignment is generally idempotent: executing `x = y` twice is the same as executing it once. (Obviously not if `x` is some hardware register which triggers an external effect.)

Comment: @Kaz: I think "idempotence" is actually very similar to the mathematical meaning, if you interpret any statement as a mathematical function which takes the complete state of the program and returns a new one.

Answer (score 7):

As the one who implement this **tool**, `startHttpServer`, you should be trying to make it the most simple, smooth and **seamless** to use...

### The function's logic

Technically, by splitting `startHttpServer`'s logic into 2 functions **and** calling them **separately**, all what you do is **moving** `startHttpServer`'s [idempotency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) into the code calling both functions instead... Furthermore, unless you wrap both logic in a third function (which is what does `startHttpServer` in first place), this forces you to write unDRYed code, duplicating it exponentially everywhere you'd have to call `startHttpServer`. In short, `startHttpServer` **has to** call itself the `isHttpServerRunning` function.

So my point is:

- Implement `isHttpServerRunning` function because this may be needed independently anyway...
- Implement `startHttpServer` making it use `isHttpServerRunning` to define its next action accordingly...

Still, you can make `startHttpServer` return any value the user of this function may need, eg:

- `0` => server starting failure
- `1` => server starting success
- `2` => server was started already

### The function's naming

First of all, what is the **primary goal** of the user? To *start HTTP server*, right?

Fundamentally, there is no problem by intending to start something that have been started already, AKA `1*1=1`. So, at least to me, calling it "`ensureHttpServerIsRunning`" seems not critically needed, I'd care more about how long, natural and memorable the function's name is.

Now if you want to know how work in detail the function under the hood, there is the documentation or code source for that, I mean like for any other function from library/framework/API/etc...

You **learn** the function once while you **write** it multiple times...

So anyway, I'd stick with `startHttpServer` which is shorter, simpler and more explicit than `ensureHttpServerIsRunning`.

Comment: Especially since the method must take some configuration arguments, like root directory, security settings, possibly a port number, I'm 100% comfortable with "start" here.

Comment: @user949300: The caller of "ensureHttpServerIsRunning" doesn't care about configuration, root directory etc. That's the business of the person who implements it.

Comment: @gnasher729 That assumes the http server is a Singleton.  Singletons are evil.  And possibly inappropriate here.  One could easily have multiple servers on multiple ports.  If there is truly just one http server, this entire method is, IMO, bad design  Better to just start the server once at program initialization.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that your colleague meant that `startHttpServer` is doing too much:

- Checking whether the server is already running,
- Starting the server if needed.

Those are two unrelated parts of code. For instance, a similar situation exists when a desktop application should ensure that it's not already running when launched; there will be a part of code which handles app instances (for instance using a mutex), and the code which will start the application message loop.

This means that **you have to have not one, but at least¹ two methods**:

- `isHttpServerRunning: boolean`
- `startHttpServer`

The application entry point will call the first method, and then the second one if the return value is `false`. Now, every method is doing one and one thing, and is easy to understand.

---

<sup>¹ If the logic needed to know if the server is already running is too complex, it may require further separation into multiple methods.</sup>

Comment: Now something else calling the two functions is doing two things, plus, exposing the functions separately may introduce race conditions. No free lunch.

Comment: If that's too much for the colleague, good luck.

Comment: @gnasher729: this answer does not contradict yours - quite the opposite, it might indeed be a good ideat to combine the renaming of the method with splitting it up into two. And as long as we don't see the real code, we don't know how complex the code is.

Comment: There are big chances, that you'll make both methods private and expose some `ensureHttpServerRunning` instead. The only problem with the original state was wrong naming.

Comment: This answer seem to oppose abstraction and DRY. What if `startHttpServer` is called more than one place in the code? Should multiple similar lines be copy-pasted everywhere? Should this be done with all functions? Pretty soon you program will be infinite size.

Comment: I think the first side-effect of this approach is that the start of the `startHttpServer` method will look roughly like `if (isHttpServerRunning()){ return; }`.  You're asserting a business rule that "it's not valid to start the http server if it's already running", but then making it someone else's responsibility to enforce that rule.  Ad-hoc and repeatedly in every location where they might call `startHttpServer`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't specify a language, in JavaScript many libraries have a "once" function [e.g. Underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166101/what-is-it-used-for-once-in-underscore).  So, if that would be familiar to you, call it a "once" pattern and possibly rename your method.

Myself, coming more from Java, the terms "caching" or "lazy evaluation" come to mind.  "Idempotent" is technically correct and a good choice, esp. if you have a more functional background.

Comment: It might not be "once", if the server can be stopped.

Comment: @gnasher729.  I could imagine a rarely used `restartHttpServer()` method.  But **just stopping** - what's the use case there?  You like sporadic connection failures?  :-)

Comment: There doesn't need to be a use case for just stopping the HTTP server because it may have been stopped by something external to the program itself - the HTTP server may have segfaulted and died, an admin may have manually stopped it for some reason, etc.

Comment: Dave, a crash is "exceptional" and should be handled as such.  Besides, since a crash can happen **anytime**, wouldn't every line of your code have to be `ensureRunning()`?  :-)  As for the admin stopping it, having this other code constantly restarting while the admin is trying to modify or fix something would be incredibly annoying and wrong.  Let the admin restart it, not the code.

Answer (score -2):

I'd prefer `startHttpServerIfNotIsRunning`.

This way, the condition is clearly mentioned already in the method name. `Ensure` or `makeSure` seems a bit vague to me, as it is not a technical expression. It sound like we don't know exactly what's going to happen.

Comment: I'm assuming you're not a native speaker? Because [ensure](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ensure) has the exact definition of what we're going for. But still it's a fair point that documentation and APIs should not require native English speaker levels to be understandable.

Comment: Thanks I exactly not what `Ensure` means. I still don't like this word for a technical expression. `Ensure` is something human. A system cannot ensure anything, it only will do what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @Voo - I'm a native speaker and I'm not sure what ensure means.

Comment: Since everyone posting here has access to the internet, why wouldn't they look up the definition of 'Ensure' if they weren't sure what it meant? A bit of trivia...many people interchange the usage of 'Ensure' and 'Assure' without realizing that using one of those words could inadvertently make them 'legally' responsible while the other would not.

Comment: @jcast: Seriously?

Comment: @Dunk and then there is 'Insure'.

Answer (score -3):

What your colleague should have told you is that you have no business writing that method. It's already been written plenty of times, and written better than you're likely to write it. For example:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/systemd_module.html
https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.service.html

From an architectural perspective, having some arbitrary bit of code managing a web server is the stuff of nightmares. Unless managing services is exclusively what your code does. But I'm guessing you didn't write monit (or kubernetes or ...).

Comment: The language is Java and the method was designed to start a grizzly embedded server in a stand-alone Jersey application. I can't fault the accuracy of your comment, given I didn't give you much context, but you assumed a lot in making your statement. It's perfectly fine to have a method that calls into jetty or grizzly to start the server.

Comment: There are millions of business applications that include self-hosted HTTP server to provide an API. And all of those will need some very simple code that actually sets up the library they're using and provides information such as which interface to bind on, which port to use, security settings, etc. Having a `startServer` function or similar is anything but uncommon. That doesn't mean you'll write the nitty-gritty low level details.